# Python - Use object as parameter to function

Tags: python

I have a function in a loop that takes 5 parameters, saves them and uses their new values over and over again. But it looks messy and I wonder if I can make a class for these variables, and just use an object as parameter in my function.

```
while encounter:
    player, minion, monster, arrow, encounter = fight(player, minion, monster, arrow, encounter)
```

Is it possible? If so, how do I do it? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, class with those five attributes and the method `fight()`.

Comment: You can make a class, but this isn't the place for tutorials. If you head over to the python.org website, the documentation section probably has a tutorial to help you get started.

Comment: Or a `dict`, if you need a lot of flexibility about what data is stored.

Comment: Store in a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) or create a new class. If you don't know how to do that check out some tutorials. Starting with this one: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you're trying to do, you might try using a [dictionary](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_dictionaries.php).

```
characterObject = {
    "player": player,
    "minion" : minion,
    "monster": monster,
    "arrrow": arrow,
    "encounter": encounter
}
```

You can then pass that single object to a function, and the receiving function could look something like:

```
def testFunc(characterObject):
    #Print the value of the "player" key
    print(characterObject["player"])
    #call some other function 
    otherFunc(characterObject["arrow"])

testFunc(characterObject)
```